# Delay stops execution forever sometimes

Tags: c++, arduino-nano

I have an arduino to control an irrigation system, consisting on one pump (called "bomba" on the code) and 5 12V water valves.

Each valve controls one irrigation circuit and the idea is to open each one sequentially during one minute and then move on to the next one.

The code is this:

```
const int TIEMPO_RIEGO = 64; // seconds

const int TRIGGER = 5;

const int BOMBA = 6;
const int CIRCUITO_1 = 8;
const int CIRCUITO_2 = 9;
const int CIRCUITO_3 = 10;
const int CIRCUITO_4 = 11;
const int CIRCUITO_5 = 12;

const int CIRCUITOS_ACTIVOS[] = {
  CIRCUITO_1,
  CIRCUITO_2,
  CIRCUITO_3,
  CIRCUITO_4,
  CIRCUITO_5,
};

void _abrirValvula(int circuito, int t) {
    digitalWrite(circuito, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(BOMBA, HIGH);
    unsigned long waitTime = t * 1000L;
    delay(waitTime);
    digitalWrite(BOMBA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(circuito, LOW);
}

void cicloRiegoCompleto() {
  int numeroDeCircuitos = sizeof(CIRCUITOS_ACTIVOS) / sizeof(CIRCUITOS_ACTIVOS[0]);
  for (int i=0; i<numeroDeCircuitos; i++){
    _abrirValvula(CIRCUITOS_ACTIVOS[i], TIEMPO_RIEGO);
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BOMBA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CIRCUITO_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CIRCUITO_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CIRCUITO_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CIRCUITO_4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CIRCUITO_5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TRIGGER, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(TRIGGER) == HIGH) {
   cicloRiegoCompleto(); 
  }
}
```

On the pin 5 (TRIGGER) I have a raspberry pi connected that is connected to the internet also, so, when I send it a message from mi phone, it puts 3.3V on that pin and starts the process.

It has been working great for like a month or so but, a few days ago, the pump didn't stop when it should, and was still working hours after it started.

I pull the plug and, when I turn it on again, it worked correctly again for another 2 or 3 days.

But today it hasn't stop again. I have check that the pump has been working for around 15 minutes until I pulled the plug, and the first valve (CIRCUITO_1) has been opened the whole time, looks like the `for` loop is stuck in the first iteration.

So can it be some problem with the `delay` function?

For some reason it is waiting way more than it should?

It works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't so it makes me think: can it be some weird overflow issue?

Comment: The code seems legit to me. Can you log on the pi, when exactly it turns it's output on and off? Just to see, if that works correctly.

Comment: When you have this problem, what is the state of the logic output of the Pi?

Comment: The pi turns its output HIGH during only one second, and then it is LOW again. But, even if it were HIGH the whole time, it should loop through each valve instead of being stuck in the first one forever.

Comment: How are you interfacing the pumps to the Arduino? Can you post a circuit diagram?
Also, how are you powering the pumps? Are they powered separately from the Arduino, or is the Arduino sourcing its power from the same circuit that the pumps are?

Comment: The valves are controlled via mosfets IRL510 (or IRL540? don't remember right now), the pump with a 5V arduino relay. Everything is powered from a 15A 12V power supply, using a step-down for the raspberry and the relay power. I'll try to upload a diagram this evening.

Comment: Is it a cheap $1 Chinese nano or a genuine Arduino nano?

Comment: Bought it on amazon.es in a pack of 6 for around 15€, so it is probably the Chinese version. I'm not sure how to spot the differences, here is a photo: https://imgur.com/03C2WyB

Comment: Cheap Chinese crap. Do you know *how* they get them so cheap? Simple: the MCUs come out of the reject bin. Instead of the factory in China throwing them out they sell them cheap on the local market. So you can expect them to be substandard and fail randomly...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your experience with the system and the source of the Nanos, the best and quickest test I can think of is to swap in a another Nano to find out whether if the problem remains or disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 10k resistors between gate and ground on your MOSFETs? You might be suffering from residual charge on your MOSFET gate keeping it on when it should be off.

Comment: Yep, and also flyback diodes on each valve.

Answer (score 0):

> It has been working great for like a month or so ... it makes me think: can it be some weird overflow issue?

It's hardly a software issue then. Nothing in your code would change after a month of operating. And if you turn the power off and on again then it would "forget" about the previous month.

> So can it be some problem with the delay function?

No.

---

I suggest looking at the hardware, or the code on the Pi.

Comment: That makes sense. The pi code looks fine but, should I just check the mosfet circuit part or the arduino itself too? What I mean: Is it possible for an arduino to break in some way that it gets stuck randomly on a line of code? Or if the arduino was broken it wouldn't work at all?

Comment: I doubt it would get "stuck" on a line of code. The processor runs or it doesn't. I would use a meter to test that the output is being set in the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem in the casting of the variable t vs the variable waittime.  t is an int and waittime is a long so when you multiply t by 1000L you may be picking up a couple of extra bytes used by other parts of the code:

For instance if t is stored at location 0x100:0x101 in RAM, and some other variable or random data is stored at 0x102:0x103, you pass 100 to the function in variable t which you expect multiplies into waittime as 100,000mS or 100S, but if the data stored at 0x102:0x103 for instance is randomly 0xFFFF, the multiplication into waittime actually works out to (100*65536)+65535 = 6,619,135mS or 1.83 hours.

The way around this is to either pass a long in the function or recast t to match waittime:

waittime = (long) t * 1000L;

Note that the order of the bytes depends on how the compiler handles variable storage.

Comment: Compilers don't overwrite memory just because you cast something. That would be pretty bad behaviour if they did. Maybe if you cast a pointer into a different sort of pointer, but this is just an ordinary variable.

Comment: The cast and multiply are almost certainly done in registers, and the variable `waitTime` is unlikely to ever have any discrete existence, as the product of the multiply will be left in registers or immediately pushed onto the stack as the argument to `delay()`, and is never referred to again.